# $\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{\text{data}}} \left[ \text{KL}(q_{\phi}(z|x) || p_{\theta}(z|x)) \right] = 0$ iff $p_\theta = p_{\text{data}}$

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $p_{\text{data}}$ be the data distribution given and assume $p_\theta, q_\phi$ be parametrized families of distributions.

**Claim.**
$p_\theta(x) = p_{\text{data}}(x)$ for all $x$ iff 
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{\text{data}}} \left[ \text{KL}(q_{\phi}(z|x) || p_{\theta}(z|x)) 
\right]
= 0.
$$

Is this claim true and how can I prove it? I tried it myself but it seems like ($\Leftarrow$) part needs additional assumptions.

Comment: Not sure if I follow your notation. But, KL divergence $ \geq 0$ due to convexity / the gibbs inequality. Therefore, it can only be $0$ when the two distributions are identical.

Comment: @EDZ Yes. So what about it?